# Windows Phone 7 - How to download SMS (text) messages to disk

Tags: windows-phone

I need to download some text messages (including date and time and sender information) on my WP7 phone, on to my desktop computer.

Is there defined way?

Comment: Why was this closed: The FAQ says this is not for electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, _except_ insofar as they interface with your computer. I want to connect my device and read information from it.

Comment: I wouldn't want to second-guess a moderator's reasons -- but your question asked about *exporting* text messages *from* the phone. It sounds like a cell phone question.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: I agree with you, @PreetSangha.  The question should not have been closed to begin with, and it has been reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fine folks at XDA would probably be more constructive for helping with this specific question.

The short answer, unfortunately, seems to be no. It's a shame that such a fine platform lacks such an elementary tool. One thread about it is here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=999376

**However, there does seem to be a messy way of doing it if you absolutely must.** Check out http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1072796. Be warned, though: here be dragons. It doesn't seem that you need to be jailbroken/unlocked for this.

Comment: So close. Download VS sp1 650m, windows phone SDK 490m. Edit Group policy to allow unsigned drivers. Have to register phone. Need to sign up - 99$ USD! All so I can download my messages.

Comment: But still not there yet

Comment: Since this works for others I'm marking this as the solution. Cheers Trey

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry to hear that! I'm currently running Android, although I do love the look of WP7 so I've taken great dismay at the fact that functionality like this is so limited. Hope you find better success in the future!

Comment: This no longer seems to work with 7.8

Answer (score 0):

To sync your WP7 addressbook you can use your live-email.
http://www.passport.net/

to sync media you can use Zune.
http://www.zune.net

To sync SMS and MMS you need to wait for an Microsoft Windows WP7 OS update. 
http://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/winphone/forum/wp7-sync/activesync-mit-windows-phone-7-m%C3%B6glich/9d7dcb2a-d898-4bb5-8e5c-d291ad19f21a

I am sorry. But you are not able to sync your SMS at this state. The only idea I can share is to mark your single SMS content, click on COPY and PASTE it in an email to yourself.

Sorry for this answer.
I am in the same boat like you.

Answer (score 0):

[Jeyo Mobile Companion](http://www.jeyo.com/companion.asp) - it has 15 days trial and can do the job for you to sync your text messages to your computer.

Comment: This only works with windows mobile 2002 not the Windows Phone 7